“you must provide a model parameter” openai api
i tried to send a http request to openai whisper-1 with VBA to transcript a speech but did not work.
i do provide a model parameter but it returns following error.
{
"error": {
"message": "you must provide a model parameter",
"type": "invalid_request_error",
"param": null,
"code": null
}
}
My code is as follows;
Public Function CreateTranscription(ByVal filePath As String, _
                                Optional MODEL As String = TRANSCRIPTION_MODEL, _
                                Optional ByVal inputText As String, _
                                Optional ByVal language As String, _
                                Optional ByVal response_format As String, _
                                Optional ByVal temperature As Integer = 0, _
                                Optional ByRef timestamp_granularities As Variant _
                                ) As Dictionary

    Dim tempStream As ADODB.Stream
    Set tempStream = New ADODB.Stream

    tempStream.Type = adTypeText
    tempStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
    tempStream.Open

    Call SetParameter(tempStream, "model", MODEL)
    Call SetBinary(tempStream, "file", filePath)

    If inputText <> "" Then
        Call SetParameter(tempStream, "prompt", inputText)
    End If

    If language <> "" Then
        Call SetParameter(tempStream, "language", language)
    End If

    Call SetFooter(tempStream)

    tempStream.Position = 0

    Dim client As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    client.setTimeouts 30000, 30000, 30000, RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SEC * 1000
    client.Open "POST", "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", True
    client.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
    client.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & OPENAI_KEY

    tempStream.Position = 0
    client.send tempStream
    client.waitForResponse RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SEC

    Select Case client.Status
        Case Is >= 500
            Debug.Print client.responseText
            Err.Raise BASE_ERROR_NUMBER + client.Status, _
            Description:="Saver Error" & vbCrLf & _
            client.responseText
        Case 400
            Debug.Print BASE_ERROR_NUMBER + client.Status & vbCrLf & client.responseText
            Err.Raise BASE_ERROR_NUMBER + client.Status, _
            Description:="Client Error" & vbCrLf & _
            client.responseText
        Case 401
            Debug.Print client.responseText
            Err.Raise BASE_ERROR_NUMBER + client.Status, _
            Description:="Invalid API KEY" & vbCrLf & _
            client.responseText
        Case Is > 400
            Debug.Print client.responseText
            Err.Raise BASE_ERROR_NUMBER + client.Status, _
            Description:="Other Call Error" & vbCrLf & _
            client.responseText
    End Select

    Dim response As Dictionary

    Set CreateTranscription = JsonConverter.ParseJson(client.responseText)

    tempStream.Close
    Set tempStream = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub SetParameter(ByRef tempStream As Object, ByVal key As String, ByVal val As String)
    
    If tempStream.Type <> adTypeText Then
        Dim p As Long
        p = tempStream.Position
    
        tempStream.Type = adTypeText
        tempStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
        
        tempStream.Position = p
    End If

    Dim param As String
    param = ""
    param = param & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
    param = param & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" & """" & key & """" & vbCrLf
    param = param & vbCrLf
    param = param & val & vbCrLf
    
    tempStream.WriteText param

End Sub

Private Sub SetBinary(ByRef tempStream As Object, ByVal paramName As String, ByVal filePath As String)

    If tempStream.Type <> adTypeText Then
        Dim p As Long
        p = tempStream.Position
        tempStream.Position = 0

        tempStream.Type = adTypeText
        tempStream.Charset = "UTF-8"

        tempStream.Position = p
    End If

    Dim param As String
    param = ""
    param = param & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
    param = param & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & paramName & """; filename=""" & filePath & """" & vbCrLf
    param = param & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf
    param = param & "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" & vbCrLf
    param = param & vbCrLf

    ' Write the form-data header text for the image
    tempStream.WriteText param

    ' Switch stream to binary type for writing the file content
    If tempStream.Type <> adTypeBinary Then
        Debug.Print "adTypeBinary"
        p = tempStream.Position
        tempStream.Position = 0
        tempStream.Type = adTypeBinary
        tempStream.Position = p
    End If

    ' Load the file content into the stream
    Dim fileStream As Object
    Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fileStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    fileStream.Open
    fileStream.LoadFromFile filePath

    tempStream.Write fileStream.Read

    fileStream.Close
    Set fileStream = Nothing

    ' Switch back to text type for further text additions
    If tempStream.Type <> adTypeText Then
        p = tempStream.Position
        tempStream.Position = 0

        tempStream.Type = adTypeText
        tempStream.Charset = "UTF-8"

        tempStream.Position = p
    End If

    tempStream.WriteText vbCrLf
End Sub


Private Sub SetFooter(ByRef tempStream As Object)

    If tempStream.Type <> adTypeText Then
        Dim p As Long
        p = tempStream.Position
        tempStream.Position = 0
    
        tempStream.Type = adTypeText
        tempStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
        
        tempStream.Position = p
    End If
    
    tempStream.WriteText "--" & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf

End Sub

What am I missing?
I tried with a real api key, not “OPENAI_KEY”.
The string "boudary" is correctly set to "-----------------------------102852708831426".
thank you!
